# How do I print the output of a field as a link on node.tpl.php?

Tags: theming

How do I print the output of a field as a link on node.tpl.php? I'm able to print the raw output of a field using this:

```
<?php $display = array('label' => 'hidden');
$view = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_podcast_url', $display);
print drupal_render($view);?><?php $display = array('label' => 'hidden');?>
```

The problem occurs when I try to make it as a link using this method:

```
<?php $display = array('label' => 'hidden'); 
$view = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_podcast_url', $display); ?>
<a href="<?php print drupal_render($view); ?>">text</a>
```

The output looks like this:

http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/211653270-scott-johnson-27-tms-846.mp3
">text

and the link points to this:

```
http://controldaily.dev/<div class=
```

I've looked around at solving this issue and can't find a solution. Anything else just shows nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it's happening because you are trying to input the entire rendered field (including styling) into the links href.

As per the description:

> The field_view_value() function can be used to output a single formatted field  value, without label or wrapping field markup.

To use field_view_field, try something like:

```
if($node->type == 'article')
{
    $link_field = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_href');
    print l(t($link_field['#items'][0]['safe_value']), $link_field['#items'][0]['safe_value']);
}
```

This example assumes a node of article type, and a field with a machine name field_href. running it through l() (despite using the safe value) will help ensure it is sanitised properly before being output.

You can also take a look at the [Link field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/link):

> The link module can be count to the top 50 modules in Drupal
>   installations and provides a standard custom content field for links.
>   With this module links can be added easily to any content types and
>   profiles and include advanced validating and different ways of storing
>   internal or external links and URLs. It also supports additional link
>   text title, site wide tokens for titles and title attributes, target
>   attributes, css class attribution, static repeating values, input
>   conversion, and many more.

Comment: This is a great start but I need to pass this through a media player so how do I print the output like <a href="$output">?

Comment: the l() function produces it for you? do you mean you need a specific id or class? there is no functional difference between manually creating the tag with <a> and the l() except l() sanitises the output first